# How can I make my UITableView request the X next cells that are outside the visible table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to have my UITableView load 3 or 4 cells outside of the table so that any data to be shown there is already loaded when I scroll down.

I have some images, and data that must be downloaded before it can be shown in the cell.
This causes a visible delay before the images are loaded when scrolling.

I can manually trigger loading of this data by doing it in the `UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. I've done this before, but I'm curious if there's an easier way to do it.

Is there any way to expand the reusable cell pool, or adjust how the cells are loaded/recycled?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I have lazy loading of images and data in place.

Everything works fine, I just wanted an easy solution to the "prefetching" problem.
 Which can be solved in many ways that has nothing to do with the view itself. Right now you can easily see the images load as you scroll. I just wanted them to load right before they become visible.

Comment: You can use an NSOperation and perform lazy loading?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Sure, I've done this before. I was just asking for a "shortcut" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for an asynchronous table view that loads the data asynchronously.

Apple provides a sample app demonstrating this:
[LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Of course, you could pre-cache the data and begin downloading data into your datasource before they scroll.

The general idea is that you are loading data into a datasource (that is separate from the UI), so you can do this at any time (and in the background). You can display temporary data or some type of loading image or spinner if the data isn't loaded yet.

Comment: The data is already loading lazily. Everything is smooth and responsive. I just wanted to cheat a bit so that I start loading the contents for eg. 8 instead of 5 cells without adding complex pre-loading logic.

Comment: I will put this as accepted as it's really the easiest solution, even though it doesn't answer my question specifically.

Comment: @Nailer, you can do the look-ahead in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Simply load rows `indexPath.row` + *n*.

Comment: Sure. That's exactly what I've done before. I just wanted this for "free".

Answer (score 1):

If data of the cell will be loaded when cel becomes visible, you can programmatically scroll the table view by scrolling to the bottom cell and go back to the first cell without animation. Another way would be creating all the cells and placing them into array when your view controller is created, and feed the table from that array that contains already created cells. I think there is no way to extend the cell pool as you are asking. Hope this helps, Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, the scrolling without animation trick is actually a bit clever. It won't work for continuous user scrolling of the table though.